# videojs play button is not working while using on javascript response

Tags: javascript, ajax, video.js

Here is my code which I tried to using vidoejs but not working play button on response of javascript. I have required that kind of script on my file. I have tried to find but no one give proper result. Can you please help me to fix this issue.

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.6.6/video.js"></script>

<video id="video_source"
class="video-js "
controls
preload="auto"
data-setup="{}"
style="width: 100%;height: auto;">
<p class="vjs-no-js">
To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
<a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
</p>
</video>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
var video_url = "videos/3D2EE6C8325B48068FF2F56FCE.mp4";
var video_src = '<source src="'+video_url+'" type="video/mp4" />';
$(".vjs-tech").html(video_src);
videojs("video_source");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, I have actual mp4 video in the url.

Comment: Do you have any error on your console ?

Comment: There is no error in console. <video id="video_source_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" style="width: 100%;height: auto;" tabindex="-1" role="application"><source src="uploads/videos/3D2EE6C8325B48068FF2F56FCE.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>

Comment: Above code display after script perform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To programmatically set the source of your video element with *videojs*, you can use [`src(sourceopt)`](https://docs.videojs.com/player#src):

```
$(function() {
  var video_url = "SampleVideo.mp4";
  videojs("video_source")
    .src(video_url);
});
```

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35152033/5156280)